# Ktor client - CSRF post request

Tags: django, kotlin, csrf, ktor, django-csrf

I am doing a project where I am using django for server and ktor client for jetpack compose application to make request.However the CSRF protection reject my login request(An unsafe post request).

As django has a built-in CSRF protection middleware, when I am testing the login post request with localhost, the server return `Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /user/login/` to the client and the login function cannot work. I tried to search for some documents and solutions to disable CSRF check (@csrf_exempt) but they are not working for me.I have added the CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS in setting.py as the following(To be honest I don't know if these works or not):

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = [
    'http://localhost',
    'http://*.127.0.0.1:*',
    'http://10.0.2.2',
    'http://127.0.0.1',
    'https://127.0.0.1',
    'https://127.0.0.1:*',
    'https://127.0.0.1:',
]
```

I have also tried to disable the middleware but not work.

Is there any way that I can use ktor client to satisfy the CSRF thing from django?? Or what else should I do if that is not possible.

Thank you for any answer.

Comment: I suggest reading this article https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/csrf/ to figure out how to send a CSRF token from a Ktor client.

Comment: Thx for your suggestion. I have read the document and now I think I need to set the header of the ktor request with a CSRF cookie. But how can I generate the CSRF cookie and set it with the header in the request? The document and example of ktor only show how to get the cookie from response but not how to generate and set the cookie.

Comment: The Cookie sending is described in https://ktor.io/docs/request.html#cookies

Comment: But how can I generate the value of the token in the cookie?

Comment: As far as I understand, you need to send it somehow to the client. `CsrfViewMiddleware sends this cookie with the response whenever django.middleware.csrf.get_token() is called. It can also send it in other cases. For security reasons, the value of the secret is changed each time a user logs in.`

Comment: Thx for your help, now the problem should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In django views.py I add a function like this:

```
@csrf_exempt
def get_csrf(request):
    token = csrf.get_token(request)
    response = JsonResponse({'detail': 'CSRF cookie set','CSRFToken': token})
    return response
```

In the ktor client , I add something like this:

```
@Serializable
data class Csrf_response(
    val detail:String,
    val CSRFToken : String,
)

private suspend fun getCsrf():Csrf_response{
        return httpClient.post("${hostUrl}/user/get_csrf/").body()
    }

    
    suspend fun postLogin(loginCredential: LoginCredential): UserInfo {
        val token =  getCsrf()
//        Log.d("token: ",token.CSRFToken)
        return httpClient.post("${hostUrl}/user/login/") {
            setBody(loginCredential)
            cookie(name = "X-CSRFToken", value = token.CSRFToken)
            header("X-CSRFToken",token.CSRFToken)
        }.body()
    }
```

The function `get_csrf` in views.py generate a random csrf token.

The `getCsrf()` function in ktor client get the generated csrf token.

Then in your login(or whatever request needs csrf) add the header and cookie and set the value of the token.

This might not be the best solution but it implements the csrf validation in ktor(I think).